# Javascript array contains where key is either string or array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array which looks like:

```
var data = [{
    key: ['blue-berries', 'strawberries'],
    title: 'Berries',
}, {
    key: 'chicken',
    title: 'Chicken',
}, {
    key: 'beef',
    title: 'Beef',
}, {
    key: 'something-else',
    title: 'Something Else',
}]
```

Assuming my 'query' was something like `'/strawberries-with-some-other-stuff'`

We should return the first item in the example array.

`'/beef-with-some-other-whatever'`
Would return the 3rd (and so on)

As you can see, some `key` properties are arrays, others are just static strings

The following appears to work, using lodash `_.find`

```
var input = '/strawberries-with-some-other-stuff';

var result = _.find(data, function(d) {

    if (d.key instanceof Array) {
        return _.forEach(d.key, function(key) {
            if (input.indexOf(key + '-') == 0) {
                console.log('key- ', key + '-')
                return d
            } else return null;
        });
    } else {
        if (input.indexOf(d.key + '-') == 0) {
            return d
        }
    }
});
```

However, it's a false positive, as if I change `input` to `'/beef-with-some-other-whatever'` it still returns the first item in the array

I presume I'm misusing _.find somehow...
Is there a better way?

Comment: Will the words be separated by `-`?

Comment: should test the indexOf == 1 for the "/" or am I missing something ?

Comment: @AmitJoki - usually, but this cannot be guaranteed

Comment: @Hacketo - Good point - in my actual app i replace '/' with ''

Comment: this code is working for me with indexOf == 1 and "/beef-with-some-other-whatever"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = '/strawberries-with-some-other-stuff';

var result = _.find(data, function (el) {
  if (Array.isArray(el.key)) {
    return _.find(el.key, function (k) {
      return input.indexOf(k + '-') >= 0;  // or return input.indexOf(k + '-') == 0; - need replace first symbol '/' 
    });
  }

  return input.indexOf(el.key + '-') >= 0;  // or return input.indexOf(el.key + '-') == 0; - need replace first symbol '/' 
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kucec/3/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

I don't know lodash or underscore or whatever. I think you could do it in native js

```
var str = "/beef-with-some-other-whatever";
var obj = data.filter(function(o){
    return str.match(/\w+/g).some(function(word){ 
       ~(word+"").indexOf(word);
    });
})[0];
```

Note that if `word` happened to be Array, it would call `join(",")` so it would still work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points you're missing here:

- You're returning a value from inside a `forEach` callback. That doesn't make any sense and it doesn't have any effect on anything.
- The function you pass to `_.find` should be a *predicate*. That means it returns either true or false.

The following should work for your requirement:

```
var input = '/strawberries-with-some-other-stuff';

var result = _.find(data, function(d) {
    if (d.key instanceof Array) {
        return !!_.find(d.key, function(key) {
            return input.indexOf(key + '-') === 0;                
        });
    } 

    return input.indexOf(d.key + '-') === 0;
});
```

There is some duplicate code here, so you can simplify this a bit further:

```
var input = '/strawberries-with-some-other-stuff';

var result = _.find(data, function(d) {
    function matchesQuery(keyStr) { return input.indexOf(keyStr + '-') === 0; } 

    return (d.key instanceof Array)
        ? !!_.find(d.key, matchesQuery)
        : matchesQuery(d.key);
});
```